# Selenium-Webdriver Node.js Can't Find New Window

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running a selenium-webdriver javascript scraper, which logs into a site and clicks a button that launches a new tab/window. I'm trying to switch the driver to focus on the newly generated window, but Selenium cannot find it.  The code I have to look:

```
driver.sleep(10000).then(function() {
    driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    })
})
```

Which prints

```
[ '287ab61a-b155-46de-a2a6-298e0e98e440' ]
```

Which is the original browser window. What could cause Selenium to not pick up on the new window?

Comment: try to print the size of number of elements you are getting from the method `getAllWindowHandles()`

Comment: I just tried. The output: 1

Comment: are u sure new windows are getting opened?

Comment: I can see it, as I'm not running headless.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use whenever I need to switch to a new tab:

```javascript
const tabs = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
await driver.switchToWindow(tabs[1]);
```

If you want to switch back to the main tab just use `tab[0]`.